# How to wrap a UEFI Driver (EDK II) With a New Protocol

Tags: protocols, uefi, edk2

I'm trying to take a UEFI driver from a 3rd party and wrap it in a different protocol GUID of my own to simplify the interface which is used by a sample application.

I do not want to make changes (other than maybe a GUID change when requesting `LocateHandleBuffer()`) to the sample application which was originally tied to a driver of my own (not 3rd party) where I didn't have to do any wrapping.

Given that I can't really associate the wrapper with a controller handle or use the USB IO protocol, it seems this does not qualify as a driver anymore.

Is there a way to do this so that I can still provide an abstracted loadable image for the sample application to use, or do I ultimately have to do this wrapping in source in the demo application?

Comment: Write a driver that locates the existing handle and uses InstallProtocolInterface to attach a new protocol object to the handle using your GUID. After that, the application can obtain your new protocol by calling LocateHandleBuffer with the GUID of your protocol. You don't even need to use a new GUID, as long as the new implementation has the same methods and behavior as the prior implementation of the protocol. I don't think you have to worry about your driver not being directly associated with a device.

Comment: In addition to the API methods, the protocol object in the driver needs to contain a pointer to the underlying protocol of the device, so it can forward calls to it. The object can of course contain any other data it needs to do its job. If that's not clear enough, I may be able to find time to write an example.

Comment: I see what you mean about not qualifying as a driver--you have no need to implement the driver binding protocol. I don't think that's a problem, though.

Comment: If I don't implement the driver binding protocol how does this new guid end up being installed?  I've more or less come to the same solution as you've suggested though.  For checking for handle support I grab handles associated with the 3rd party guid and match then with provided controller handle.